# Updating DOM as results become available

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm making asynchronous calls using Akka and return a Result with ok() once the call completes. I have several asynchronous calls that I want to make in sequence and I want to update the DOM as each call completes.

Is this possible just using Play or would I have to use AJAX? I've searched the Play documentation but haven't been able to find anything on how to do this. As far as I can see, each method in my Application.java has to return in order to update the DOM but how do I then chain several calls together that execute one after the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Manipulations with `DOM` is prerogative of `JavaScript` it doesn't matter how you make your calls. With `Play` you can either send some data with your response(JSON, XML...) or render a view and trasmit some data to the view via parameters, then dynamic part of the view could be updated with the new data.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I chain together multiple Play calls?